# How to add a .cw Postfix Template in Visual Studio\Resharper like .sout template in IntelliJ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, resharper

I am doing a transition from Java to C#.
In IntelliJ there is a Postfix Template like:

```
String expr = "John";
//writing expr.sout gives:
System.out.println(expr);
```

Is there any way to create a template like expr.cw which returns Console.WriteLine(expr); in Visual Studio\Resharper?

Comment: You really should add what you have tried to and what the errors were for it. This will give us a better understanding of what problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `JetBrains.Annotations` and create a [SourceTemplate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Source_Templates.html) is a possible solution.
For example, adding the following static class in the project:

```
using System;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace SpeechRecognition
{
    public static class ResharperHelper
    {
        [SourceTemplate]
        public static void cw(this string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            //$ $END$
        }
    }
}
```